# Does twitter's bootstrap framework support writing email?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-email

I can't seem to find it via googling.  I'm not sure this is a clear use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is much in bootstrap that is unsupported in html email. HTML email only supports [limited css](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and should be [created using tables](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/).